# Can't retrieve WPF application resource if there is only one

Tags: wpf

Is ths a bug in my code or in WFP? Using VisualStudio 2013, targeting .NET 4.5.1.

```
<Application x:Class="WPFDemo.MyApp"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFDemo.ViewModels">

    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:TestClass x:Key="tc" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

   public partial class MyApp : Application
   {  
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
         base.OnStartup(e);
         var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
         mainWindow.Show();
      }
   }

   public partial class MainWindow
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         object o = Application.Current.Resources["tc"];
      }
   }
```

Problem: o is null.

If I add at least one other resource of any type:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:TestClass x:Key="tc" />
    <vm:TestClass2 x:Key="tc2" />
</Application.Resources>
```

and make no other changes anywhere, o comes back as an instance of TestClass.

Huh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found few references to bug when `Application.Resources` don't load when `StartupURI` is not defined

- [WPF: Cannot find resource defined in the App.xaml file](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472729/wpf-cannot-find-resource-defined-in-the-app-xaml-file)
- [Application.Resources Not Loaded if  Doesn't Have StartupURI Property](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0d3fd0d8-ea9a-47d9-9e10-89db8b0243c3/applicationresources-not-loaded-if-application-doesnt-have-startupuri-property?forum=wpf)
- [Bug: Single  Entry Ignored](http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored)

and there seem to be 3 workarounds to this problem (4 including creating dummy resource)

**Define dictionary**

```
<Application.Resources>  
    <ResourceDisctionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries/>
        <vm:TestClass x:Key="tc" />
    </ResourceDisctionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

but it seems strange as it requires empty `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` tag

**Don't override OnStartup method** but use `Startup` event instead

```
<Application ... Startup="Application_Startup">
```

and in code

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

**Give your `Application` a name**

```
<Application ... x:Name="myApplication">
```

Comment: I went with using the Startup event. Microsoft must really not want to fix this bug...it's 4 years old?

Comment: It seems so. Don't know on which version you're working on but originally I was able to reproduce it on VS2013 and .NET 4 but now tested it on .NET 4.5.1 as well and it's still there and all methods mentioned above still work

Comment: Probably only noobs like me would run into this...I'm guessing everyone has more than one application-scoped resource? But it sure set me back, causing me to think I wasn't doing something correctly.

Comment: In 2020 this problem is still exists (VS2019/.NET Framework 4.7.2). Thank you for the answer, it saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: You know what is funny. It's 2 days before year 2022. The issue is still there with VS 2019 and the last updates of everything. AND... tadam, nothing mentioned above seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a better way to solve this problem is add "InitializeComponent()" into the constructor of App class, just like:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //other codes below
        }
}
```

Comment: This was my issue...